# svg animateMotion on end event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have svg in my html with a path and a circle (with `animateMotion`) moving along the path. How do I detect when the `animationMotion` ends so that I can perform a task? also how do I reset the `animationMotion` - that is take the moving circle back to the start of the line. Below is my svg html code:

```html
<svg id="cc-line" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 -23 150 55" width="150px" height="55px" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="#2471A3" d="M0 0 l150 0" stroke="#2471A3" stroke-width="5"/>
      <circle id="cc-line-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="8" fill="#2471A3">
        <animateMotion id="cc-line-motion" path="M0 0 l150 0"
    begin= "0s" dur="6.0s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto" fill="freeze">
      </circle>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `onrepeat` event to detect when an animation cycle has completed, and run custom logic/task at that point. 
This can be achieved via javascript in the following way:

```
var animationElement = document.querySelector('#cc-line-motion');

animationElement.onrepeat = function() {

  // An animation cycle was completed
  console.log('Task run at end of animation cycle')  
}
```

This was tested in Chrome 68 - note that [this is an experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement/onrepeat) so use with caution

Answer (score 1):

> take the moving circle back to the start of the line

You can achieve this by adding keyframes to your `<animateMotion>`:

```
keyPoints="0;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear"
```

The three values in `keyPoints` represent the fraction along the line for each keyframe. "0" means the start" and "1" means the end.

The three values in `keyTimes` represent the fraction of the duration that each keyframe sits at.  "0" is the start, "0.5" is half way through, and "1" is the end.

> How do I detect when the animationMotion ends so that I can perform a task?

The best way is with the "onrepeat" event as Dacre suggested.  The event is called "repeatEvent"

```js
var anim = document.getElementById("cc-line-motion");

var i=0;

anim.addEventListener("repeatEvent", function(evt) {
  console.log("repeat "+(++i));
});
```

```html
<svg id="cc-line" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 -23 150 55" width="150px" height="55px" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#2471A3" d="M0 0 l150 0" stroke="#2471A3" stroke-width="5"/>
  <circle id="cc-line-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="8" fill="#2471A3">
    <animateMotion id="cc-line-motion" path="M0 0 l150 0"
                   begin="0s" dur="6.0s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto"
                   keyPoints="0;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, when I said take the moving circle back, I meant reset - like restart, not that it should move back along the line

Comment: Your animation is already resetting back to the start of the line.  Do you mean that you want it to run once, fire the event, then reset the circle to the start and stop there?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't "detect when it ends", but your animation runs for 6 seconds, as specified by this attribute of `<animateMotion>`: `dur="6.0s"`. So you could add some JavaScript that does this:

```
setTimeout(function, 6000);
```

And if the time changes in any way, you can use an attribute value selector as well:

```
var animationTime = document.getElementById("cc-line-motion").getAttribute("dur");
```

Comment: No worries! I'm glad to help. Was my answer the solution?